# Webcomponentjs polyfill for v1 spec

Tags: web-component, polyfills

Is there a polyfill for the Web Components v1 spec available? I'm looking for a way to create components using `customElements.define` instead of `document.registerElement`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @tony19, you can use [v1](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/tree/v1) branch of `webcomponentsjs`. You can read about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#browser-support-and-polyfills).

Or you can install it using bower

`bower i -S webcomponentsjs#v1`

Comment: Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: Actually the right statement is `bower i -S webcomponentsjs#v1` but it can be a mess with bower automatic dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to polyfill **only Custom Elements** v1 (implementing `customeElements.define`) you have the choice between 2 polyfills:

- [document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element)
- [custom-elements](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements)

---

If you want to polyfill **the whole *Web Components* stack**, you can use the [v1 branch of the webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/tree/v1) polyfill, since the current release (v0.7.23) doesn't implement yet the Custom Element and Shadow DOM "v1" Living Standards. Note that it is [not merged](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/pull/514) in the master yet and subject to changes.

You can also only load the useful polyfills depending of your needs:

- Custom Elements v1: see above
- HTML Imports: `HTMLImport.js` in the current [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) release
- Shadow DOM v1: [ShadyDOM](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom), and [ShadyCSS](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadycss)
- Templates ([old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=template) only :) `Template.js` in the current webcomponentsjs release