# webkit vs custom elements v2

Tags: safari, webkit, mobile-safari, custom-element

1. is webkit trying to accomplish the same thing as custom elements v2 ?

   https://webkit.org/

   https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements
2. If so will safari ever support custom elements? Apple dev's website claims they will, but then they reference 'webkit' and not 'custom elements'. This makes me worried that Safari 10.1 will still not run the 'custom elements' I programmed for my website. True or false?

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html

3. If safari will never support custom elements, does anyone know of a 'wrapper' or some way to write custom elements with one source-code base, but also have the website run on safari?
4. Why would google chrome today (march 28,2017), which supports custom elements, not render properly from iPad, but would work fine when using the browser from mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is webkit trying to accomplish the same thing as custom elements v2 ?

Webkit, Safari's Web engine, is trying to implement Custom Elements v1.

> If so will safari ever support custom elements?

[Yes](http://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements%20v1), at least autonomous custom elements. For customized built-in elements you'll need a polyfill (see below).

> does anyone know of a 'wrapper' ?

There are [2 polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41292614/4600982) availables.

> Why would google chrome today [...] not render properly from iPad ?

Maybe you version on Chrome or OS X is too old. Maybe you can update them.

Comment: "Why would google chrome today (march 28,2017), which supports custom elements, not render properly from iPad" Because Chrome on iOS uses the Safari engine, not Blink. Chrome on OSX/macOS uses Blink.